# Wrong line-spacing with fbb package within footnotes

Tags: footnotes, line-spacing

The following example results in a file with incorrect line-spacing. The line containing the Ä and Ö has a slightly bigger spacing than all other lines within the footnote.

Other fonts don't seem to have the problem (just comment out the line for fbb to see the difference). Is there a chance to correct the spacing without touching the font sources, maybe with `\DeclareFontShape`?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fbb}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
This is a test\footnote{\blindtext[2] To show that some characters may 
cause trouble with line-spacing as there are the German Umlauts Ä and Ö.
What is wrong with them? \blindtext}
\end{document}
```

Comment: do you want to shrink the font, or increase the linespace to get even spacing? (either is possible)

Comment: I guess even spacing is what my client wants.

Comment: yes but the accented letters do not fit in that space so you can either increase the baseline space for the entire document so accented letters in that font fit or you can scale the font to be a bit smaller so the accented letters fit in the current space

Comment: Thank you. I will probably increase the baselineskip for `\footnotesize`then.